# String manipulation in C (replace & insert characters)

Tags: c, string, printf

I am very new in C, I have little idea about `sprintf` but I can't fulfill my requirement.

I have a `char *` variable which contains string like below :

```
date=2013-12-09 time=07:31:10 d_id=device1 logid=01  user=user1 lip=1.1.1.1 mac=00:11:22:33:44:55 cip=2.2.2.2 dip=3.3.3.3 proto=AA sport=22 dport=11 in_1=eth1 out_1=
```

I want an output as

```
2013-12-09#07:31:10#device1#01#user1#1.1.1.1#00:11:22:33:44:55#2.2.2.2#3.3.3.3#AA#22#11#eth1##
```

if some value is null after `=` it should print `##` in sequence.

Comment: give some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example by use strtok, strchr, sprintf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    const char *data = "date=2013-12-09 time=07:31:10 d_id=device1 logid=01  user=user1 lip=1.1.1.1 mac=00:11:22:33:44:55 cip=2.2.2.2 dip=3.3.3.3 proto=AA sport=22 dport=11 in_1=eth1 out_1=";
    char *work = strdup(data);//make copy for work
    char *output = strdup(data);//allocate for output
    char *assignment; //tokenize to aaa=vvv
    size_t o_count = 0;//output number of character count
    for(assignment=strtok(work, " "); assignment ;assignment=strtok(NULL, " ")){
        o_count += sprintf(output + o_count, "%s#", strchr(assignment, '=')+1);
    }
    printf("%s", output);
    free(work);
    free(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for(assignment=strtok(work, " "); assignment ;assignment=strtok(NULL, " ")){
        o_count += sprintf(output + o_count, "%s#", strchr(assignment, '=')+1);
    }   this line gives segfault sometimes !!

Comment: @user95711 There is no problem, but do not or directly manipulating the string?

Comment: o_count += sprintf(output + o_count, "%s#", strchr(assignment, '=')+1);    there is something wrong is happening here. n yes I am doing the same as you suggested.

Comment: @user95711 It becomes the premise that contains the '=' always the token, but the format is or has become so? It is necessary that you want to skip the token by checking in advance because it causes a segmentation error as long as there are cases where it is not included is if '='.

Comment: @user95711 Is it possible to present the data in the case of cause an error?

Comment: see the strace in your answer

Comment: @user95711 There is no problem here. Segment fault does not occur. I think that it's because of data to be handled.

Comment: @user95711 Segment fault error happens by compiling and run my code?
Please show the code if only as occur in your code.

Comment: well actually I am using this code with open source ulogd 2.0 . in file ulogd_output_SYSLOGMU.c  if I remove this line there is no segfault.

Comment: @user95711 It is a meaningless story.

Comment: don't have you  reset the o_count ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to give you exact code but I will give you some links that will help you.

[strchr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strchr.html) :: You can use this find the position of '=' in the string.

> 1. Now, copy the string after the position of '=' till you find a 'space'.
> 2. Whenever you will find a 'space', write a '#' in the buffer.
> 3. Keep doing this, till you encounter a '\0'. Write '##' to buffer when you have encountered '\0'
> 4. Append that with a '\0'.

Ex:: [C function strchr - How to calculate the position of the character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342959/c-function-strchr-how-to-calculate-the-position-of-the-character)